# How to provide mixed orientation to Angular Material drag e drop v10

Tags: angular-material, drag-and-drop

I am using [Material drag e drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) they don't allow the mixed-orientation of the drag e drop so to use it with both directions I use this [workaround](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuiviw).

But in the last release, they removed `CdkDropList.enter` method.

So now how can I achieve the same result as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13372#issuecomment-664067103

this is the new code from angular 9 version:

```
this.source._dropListRef.start();
this.placeholder._dropListRef.enter(drag._dragRef, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetLeft, drag.element.nativeElement.offsetTop);
```